# Creating Items for an specific section

Tags: nanoc

I'm building a website with nanoc. I have my main index file and now I want to add a article section with some articles I've written. So I use:

```
nanoc create_item articles
```

to create this new section, but how do I create new items within this item I just created?

The url tree I want to achieve would be:

```
index.html
/articles/index.html
/articles/one.html
/articles/two.html
```

I now this is very basic stuff but I can't find any examples on the nanoc documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nanoc create_item articles/two`, or you can simply create `/articles/two.html` manually. The create_item command is there for your convenience but you can easily create items by hand as well.

Comment: Thanks! What would you do to create a dynamic listing of all the items which belong to the articles directory?

Comment: If `@item` is the articles item, then `@item.children` will give you the items below the `/articles/` item. Otherwise, find the articles item using `@items.find { |i| i.identifier == '/articles/' }`.